# can't get the rows item only get the count of rows ionic 3 sqlite

Tags: sqlite, ionic3

i am learning ionic 3 and i got stuck on a step where i have to check from my sqlite database when the app is loaded and check if user table has any entry if yes then get the username from the table, but when i execute the query then i get only length of the rows my query is :

```
this.db.executeSql('Select * FROM users', {})
.then(data => console.log(data))
.catch(e => console.log(e));
```

and the output that i get in the console  is:

```
{rows: {…}, rowsAffected: 0, insertId: undefined}
```

after expand console response result is

```
insertId:undefined
rows:
    item:ƒ (i)
    length:1
  __proto__:Object
  rowsAffected:0
__proto__:Object
```

if anyone know the reason why this happens please help me .you answers are very valuable for me. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe I should use the call to transcation.

[Read data from the database](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage)

**Exemple:**

```
this.db.transaction((tx: any) => {
    tx.executeSql('Select * FROM users', {},
        (tx: any, res: any) => {
            for (var x = 0; x < res.rows.length; x++) {
                console.log("row: " + res.rows.item(x));
            }
        }, (tx: any, err: any) => {
            //reject({ tx: tx, err: err })
        });

}, (err: any) => {
    //reject({ tx: tx, err: err })
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply sir, i tried your way but i cant get the rows .. but only get the rows count

Comment: It looks like your table is missing data.

Comment: The data will be made available on res.rows.item (x). And you will get res.rows.item(x).yourfield.

Comment: thanks a lot sir i got your point and get the data from my sqlite database. thank you very much really appreciate .i have a another query for you sir can read the sqlite directly from my android device ?

Comment: I believe you will have to create a new topic for this question.

Comment: replace {} with [] in line 2